# WordPress migration not showing images

Tags: wordpress, images, migration

I migrated my WordPress site from host to host, also to different domain, according to the guide at [WPExplorer](http://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/), however the images do not shown. I replaced the database records via "Search Replace DB Master" so the `old_domain.com` was set to `www.new_domain.com`. The images are still missing though (even in admin backend). If I right-click on the picture and copy its address, then put the address into browser search bar, the image works with no problems. So e.g. `www.new_domain.com/wp-content/uploads/XY.png` is the image on the web, it does not work. But if I enter this link into browser, the image does show up.
Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

OK, solved. It was caused by my Rewrite rule in *.htaccess* file which I forgot to change after migration.